# Java : How to create a 64 bit array in java to store larger than Integer_max-value

Tags: java, arrays, integer, long-integer

I am trying to find the sum of primes. To execute in smaller time I have precomputed it in a long array but the last two test cases are appearing wrong. Reason is overflow i.e. max value that can be accommodated in Integer.MAX_VALUE but I am trying to provide a large value. I need this large value :

Test Link : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler010/

This is my code  :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count,n,t;
        long ans[] = new long[10000001];
            ans[0] = 0; ans[1] = 1; ans[2] = 2; ans[3] = 5; ans[4] = 5;
       //     ans[2] = 5;
        for(int m=5;m<100000;){
            count = 0;
                    if(m%2==0){
                        count++;
                    }
         //       for(int i=3;i<=1000000;i++){

                    for(int j=3;j*j<=m;j+=2){
                        if(m%j==0){
                //            System.out.println(i);
                            count++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(count<1){
                    ans[m]=ans[m-1]+m;
           //          System.out.println(m+" : "+ans[m]);
                        m++;
                    }
                    else{
                       ans[m]=ans[m-1];
             //         System.out.println(m+" : "+ans[m]);
                        m++; 
                    }
        //        }
        } 
                t = sc.nextInt();
                while(t>0){
            n = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(ans[n]);
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your provided a broken link

Comment: there is the BigInteger class for big integers.

Comment: I just checked link is working  : https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/projecteuler/challenges/euler010

Comment: Which number is overflowing?

Comment: This part : long ans[] = new long[10000001]; When i am precomputing prime, values in this array is overflowing

Comment: The question is unclear, what is it that actually overflows? Your link to the challenge doesn't help the matter. Given the value constraints in the challenge I see no particular problem solving this with just primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to store a very large number. You can use Java's
**[Biginteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)** class:

> ***According to Java docs:***
>
> All operations behave as if BigIntegers were represented in two's-complement notation (like Java's primitive integer types). BigInteger provides analogues to all of Java's primitive integer operators, and all relevant methods from java.lang.Math. Additionally, BigInteger provides operations for ***modular arithmetic***, ***GCD calculation***, primality testing, ***prime generation***, bit manipulation, and a few other miscellaneous operations.

When we were doing system security, we need to generate large prime numbers which is more than 100 digits long. We use BigInteger.